# How to set style for email address link in Gmail?

Tags: html, css, gmail

I am making an HTML template to email messages to users. I need to make all links in the message of given color.
For the tag <a> the following variant can be used:

```
<a href="..." style="color:#009900">...</a>
```

The problem is that my template contains an email address as plain text. When the message is opened in Gmail, it makes a link from it. How to change that link's color?

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute selector:

```
a[href^="mailto"] 
{ 
    color:#009900
}
```

This will select any anchors that are mailtos.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tag with its attribute href to have mailto: in it

```
a[href^="mailto:"] {   //style your link hear  }
```

Comment: But where should I define this style? Gmail strips <style> tag.

Comment: if you tried it  then you have to write it inline to your link no other option I see but as I remember not long  before when I was working on same I use <style> and it worked fine for me yes of-course you cant include external style-sheet by <link> tag

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks, I have no access to the attributes of the '<a>' tag, because it is generated by Gmail. I've tried doing this: `<div style="a[href^="mailto"] { color:#009900 }">
<a href="mailto:rustam2890@gmail.com">blah</a>
</div>`, but it didn't worked.

Comment: That's because you can't select another element from within a style tag on one element. You can embed a style tag at the beginning of your email, Gmail will allow this. I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

separate each part of the email address alone using `span` tag
for example, if you have `example@sitename.com` it will be like below

```
<span>example</span>@<span>sitename</span>.<span>com</span>
```